# vagrant Temp files on windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using vagrant on **windows**. Stored in `C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/` I have the following folders corresponding maybe to different instanciation of a my Virtual Box (1Gb each).

```
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130315-6356-1ptg2bm/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130315-6356-hg7lmy/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130315-8124-x3hd9e/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130315-8704-1j5rshk/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130318-8492-158p1us/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130318-9304-12usn7r/
C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-20130320-6348-1cbn0vn/
```

As I'm using **VirtualBox** to run and save my last vagrant instance, I have no more recent folders and I doubt those are still relevant.

May I delete them without risk or how could I run them back from the command line to check if there would be something to save there ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these listed directories just saved states?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are saved states / snapshots :

The safest bet is to move the files, then select "Discard save state" from VirtualBox.

Start up vagrant (power it up) and you'll probably be fine. If not, just point the VM back to the save states.